# How to check whether a tab is created from an extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-headers

I want to implement a function that supporting to modify the http headers. My extension works as follow:

1. The user open a page A, then click the toolbar item of my extension.
2. My extension will open a new window(page B) and let the user fill the http headers.
3. Then I will open in a new tab(page C) with the url of init page A.
4. In my background.html, I want to use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener to listen any requests and modify the request from the page C.

My question is how can I know a request is from the new page B which opened by my extension.
I try Tab.openerTabId. But I find Tab.openerTabId is set with the tabId of the init page A, not the tabId of my extension page B.

"Tab.openerTabId == the tabId of page A" is not correct. The page with "Tab.openerTabId == the tabId of page A" contains two kinds of pages:the pages opened by page A directly and the pages opened by my extension.

Answer (score 1):

Both `chrome.windows.create` and `chrome.tabs.create` accept a callback parameter which gives off the new window/tab id. If you open with those functions, you can save these ids and check windows and tabs against them.

But you don't necessarily need those. You just need the URLs.